# $current_user var returns NULL

Tags: plugins, users

I am developing an wp plugin and I am trying to get the current user.

If i return with an error print_r($current_user) returns the needed info.

But the plugin is activated without an error it returns NULL.

I tried to include some wp core files such as wp-load etc but this doesn't have any effect.

this is my code(without the error):

```
class My_plugin_class{

    var $user;

    function __construct() 
    {
        global $current_user;

        //Set the current user
        $this->user = $current_user;

        print_r($this->user);

    }     
}
```

**EDIT:**
Just edited my code to:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

The function get_currentuserinfo() does now a print_r(); and isn't going to stop?

**EDIT:**
***Fixed it myself.***

Comment: Peter - you shouldn't need to load core files manually, please see my answer. Also - please post your solution as an answer, it makes it easier for people to distinguish between question and answers.

Comment: "Fixed it myself"... how? :) I'm currently having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you out, it's too long ago and i don't develop wordpress anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You need to globalize `$current_user`, and then populate it via `get_currentuserinfo()`. See [the Codex entry for `get_currentuserinfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo). In the Codex-example usage:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
?>
```

So, try adapting your code accordingly; e.g.:

```
class My_plugin_class{

    var $user;

    function __construct() 
    {      
        //Set the current user
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $this->user = $current_user;

        print_r($this->user);

    }     
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work either, I tried a lot but nothing seems to work. I've been stuck since a half day trying to accomplish it. In a theme it will work but in a plugin it doesn't i need to include a wordpress core file. But on my opinion it's a little bit ugly if i include some of wordpress core files.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to manually require WP files. You are probably just using the function too early, try constructing the class on `init` or have your `__construct` function hook a second function on `init` that deals with the current user.

For instance:

```
class My_plugin_class{

    var $user;

    function __construct() {      
        add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
    }     

    static function init(){
        //Set the current user
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $this->user = $current_user;
        print_r($this->user);
    }
}
My_plugin_class::__construct;
```

*Not tested*